# use socket.io in my controller with yeoman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, yeoman

I have install `yo angular-fullstack`

The source code of the project is here : [https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/tree/master/server/api/thing)

My api look like that :

```
thing
├── index.js                - Routes
├── thing.controller.js     - Controller for our `thing` endpoint
├── thing.model.js          - Database model
├── thing.socket.js         - Register socket events
└── thing.spec.js           - Test
```

How can i use the sockets in **thing.controller.js**, the socket in the clicked function doesn't work

```
/**
 * Using Rails-like standard naming convention for endpoints.
 * GET     /things              ->  index
 * POST    /things              ->  create
 * GET     /things/:id          ->  show
 * PUT     /things/:id          ->  update
 * DELETE  /things/:id          ->  destroy
 */

'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var Thing = require('./thing.model');

[...]

exports.clicked = function(req, res) {
   //Why socket is not defined ?
   socket.emit('test', data);
};
```

On my clicked function i just want to emit a socket to the client side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject your `socket.io` instance into your `thing.controller` instance...

thing.controller.js

```
module.exports = function(context) {
  var controller = {};
  ...
  controller.clicked = function(req,res){
    context.io.emit('test','data');
  }
  ...
  return controller;
}
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, context) {
  ...
  app.use('/api/things', require('./api/thing')(context));
  ...
```

app.js

```
...
require('./routes')(app, {io:socketio});
...
```

---

NOTE: This will emit the event to *ALL* listeners...

When you connect via socket.io a channel is formed between the client and server.. this shows up via the socket.io connection event's `socket` on the server...  When a REST call is made from angular.js to express, there is nothing that ties that request to the socket.io connection from the browser (or any way to know it's even from the same window in the browser).

If you need to communicate with socket.io to a specific instance, then you need to rework your angular service to use `socket.io` instead of REST, or maintain a reference table from the browser to a given socket as part of the REST request.  This is a much broader discussion, and will either be limited to a single process, or be a much larger development.

---

Towards developing against a socket.io based service, you may want to checkout at least the following...

- [angular-socket-io component](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)
- [Writing an angular.js app with socket.io](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure socket.io script is included and define sensor var for get it working as

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
```

And finally get sure clicked function is getting called when event is fired.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The socket are defined on the app.js, and the function onSave & onRemove work to.
I just want the way to call a socket in my controller.

Comment: Have you added sensor service in your controller? 

`angular.module('nodeServerApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, **socket**)`

Comment: Socket io is already defined on : https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/server/config/socketio.js
I think it's not a good idea to redifined it on the controller

Comment: You are not redefining it, just adding the sensor angular service to it for abling it use

Comment: The server side don't work with Angular, it's only Express + Socket.io. Check the source code on the demo

Comment: Buy if you see "main controller" code they add sensor service for it's use, so i suppose it connect to socket.io in server thanks to the generator config.